# Styles not applied when app starts

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a strange problem with an app developed using phonegap and jquery mobile: 
when the app starts, styles are not applied but if I browse within the app and then go back to the index, I can see styles well applied.
What should I change?
Here is my index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
var intervalloRefresh;
var intervalloRisultati;
var iter=0;

// Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// Cordova is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script> --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<style>
    #pulsantiera{width:25%;height:100%;float:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page"> 
      <div data-role="content"> 
        <div id="pulsantiera" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
            <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onclick="capturePhoto();">Allineamento</a> -->
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onclick="allinea();">Allinea</a>
            <a href="percorsi.html" data-role="button">Percorsi</a>
            <a href="programma.html" data-role="button">Programma</a>
            <a href="video.html" data-role="button">Info</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onclick="capturePhoto();">Foto</a>
            <a href="chat.html" data-role="button">Chat</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onclick="vote('y');">Y</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onclick="vote('a');">A</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onclick="vote('n');">N</a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:74%;height:100%;margin-left:26%"  >   
            <h1 id="title">PATH</h1>
            <div id="content">
                <img src="images/IT_MAPPA.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="vote" stle="display:none"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the position of your CSS and JS files?

If parsed from top to bottom:

```
1) jquery is initialized
2) jquery mobile is initialized
3) then the CSS is loaded
```

So the CSS needed for the JQM widgets is not there when JQM kicks into gear.

Try switching to:

```
1) all CSS 
2) jquery 
3) jquery mobile
```

Also check the [JQM page template](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-template.html). The CSS always goes first.

Comment: Thank you. I tried switching as you say but without success.
Finally I used a trick:
1. load a blank page carrying all the styles
2. onload change page to my real index

Now it works. Maybe a HW-related issue?
My tablets are Motorola Xoom2 and Samsung Galaxy P7500